# In HTML I can make a checkmark with &#x2713; . Is there a corresponding X-mark?

Tags: html, encoding, symbols, entities

Is there a corresponding X mark to ✓ (`&#x2713;`)? What is it?

Answer (score 305, accepted):

A corresponding cross for ✓ `&#x2713;` would be ✗ `&#x2717;` I think (Dingbats).

Comment: perfect, thanks.  any idea where I can get a reference for these like the ascii lookup tables?

Comment: The complete reference is called Unicode! You could look amongst the “Symbols/Other” character, perhaps (though you font probably won't have glyphs for much of it): http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/So/list.htm

Comment: I just tested and this doesn't work in IE 8... IE 9, FireFox, and Chrome work correctly. Here's a good link to more symbols: http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=dingb

Comment: use "Code Decimal" works also in IE 8, but "Code Hex" does not.

Comment: As I mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25652166/4794), @nc., the [&what search site](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/x) is a nice reference with a good search, and it displays the entity name if there is one.

Answer (score 179):

✗

```
&#x2717;
```

✘

```
&#x2718;
```

✕

```
&#x2715;
```

✖

```
&#x2716;
```

Answer (score 43):

Personally, I like to use named entities when they are available, because they make my HTML more readable. Because of that, I like to use `&check;` for ✓ and `&cross;` for ✗. If you're not sure whether a named entity exists for the character you want, try the [&what search site](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/x). It includes the name for each entity, if there is one.

As mentioned in the comments, `&check;` and `&cross;` are not supported in HTML4, so you may be better off using the more cryptic `&#x2713;` and `&#x2717;` if you want to target the most browsers. The most definitive references I could find were on the W3C site: [HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html#h-24.2.1) and [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#named-character-references).

Comment: I'm really surprised no one talked about it or gave you more +1 for that!

Comment: Thanks, @Cyril, but I did answer the question five years after the other answers. It might take a while for my answer to get noticed. I'm patient.

Comment: From http://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp, it looks like check and cross aren't supported in HTML4 or below.

Comment: Good to know, @mwfearnley, I've added a warning about HTML4.

Answer (score 30):

It's between the Z and the C on your keyboard.

Comment: it can also be either T, N or S

Comment: I believe the question is asking for the symbol `x` not the letter. They look alike but are definelty not the same.

Comment: As a matter of fact, it's between the K and the B on *my* keyboard! ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I think this will help everyone.

All codes are taken from here - https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/symbols/

✗

```
&#x2717;
```

✘

```
&#x2718;
```

✕

```
&#x2715;
```

✖

```
&#x2716;
```

✓

```
&#x2713;
```

✔

```
&#x2714;
```

☑

```
&#x2611;
```